# converting the POCO Model into MongoDB's Bson format

Tags: c#, mongodb, annotations, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

Here is the information about my development environment:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

.NET Framework 4.6

ASP.NET MVC   assembly System.Web.Mvc  Version=5.2.3.0

MongoDB.Driver 2.0.1.27

Mongodb 3.0.6

Within my C# application, I have the following code that retrieves a MongoDB database reference:

```
 public class MongoDBConnectionManager
 {

     public IMongoDatabase getMongoDB() {

            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            IMongoDatabase iMgDb = client.GetDatabase("foo");
            IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> UserDetails = 
            iMgDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");
            return iMgDb;
     } // end of public IMongoDatabase getMongoDB()

  } // end of public class MongoDBConnectionManager
```

Here is the POCO class that represent a User Business Entity:

```
 using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

 public class UserModel
 {

    public object _id { get; set; } //MongoDb uses this field as identity.

   [BsonId]
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   [Required]
   //[DataType(DataType.Password)]
   [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
   public string Password { get; set; }

   [Required]
   // [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
   [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
   public string Email { get; set; }


   [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
   public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

   [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
   public string Address { get; set; }

 }
```

Here is the DAO C# class that uses the Mongo DB Connection Manager Class:

```
   public class DAO
   {

       public int insertNewUser(UserModel um)
       {
         MongoDBConnectionManager mgoDBCntMng = new MongoDBConnectionManager();
         IMongoDatabase database = mgoDBCntMng.getMongoDB();
         IMongoCollection <BsonDocument> UserDetails = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");
         UserDetails.InsertOneAsync(um);

         return 0;
      }
  }
```

The problem that I'm facing is with the following line of code in the DAO class:

```
  UserDetails.InsertOneAsync(um);
```

Visual Studio Community 2015 displays the following error:

```
  cannot convert from 'UserModel' to MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument
```

I believe the error has something to do with somehow translating the  UserModel POCO into MongoDB's Bson format.  Therefore, in my UserModel POCO, I used the use space called MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes because I thought we needed to use MongoDB Annotations.  However, it still failed to solve the problem.

Could someone please tell me how to correct the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove the _id property from your model as it is generated by mongo and you don't need to add it yourself. Also you can mark all your properties that should be included in the model with [BsonElement] attribute except the [BsonId].

Also you should serialize and deserialize to your own model not BsonDocument :

```
MongoCollection<UserModel> userDetails = database.GetCollection<UserModel>("Users");
userDetails.InsertOneAsync(um);
```

You are creating your custom class and trying to fetch and insert BsonDocument without any conversion. If you want to work directly with BsonDocument you can call something like this:

```
var umToBson = um.ToBsonDocument();
```

and then insert it as you are trying to.

Comment: You don't need to mark everything with BsonElement. The driver will pick up any public property by itself. You also don't need to tell us that a string property should be represented as a string. I'd suggest removing all attributes and putting back only the ones that you end up needing. Do remove that _id though. The "ID" property is marked with BsonId, indicating for it to be used as the identifier.

Comment: Thx dlght & @craig-wilson , could you please tell me how I can specify public int ID { get; set; } to auto-increment from within the POCO called UserModel?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support auto-incrementing fields. You'll either have to build that yourself, or use an ObjectId.

Comment: can we stop marking all element one by one, and leave it at mongo db hands?